# Rails: Sidebar Conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a sidebard to display `@notices`

```
<% @notices.each do |notice| %>
<li class="list-group-item notice"><%= short_auto_link(notice.content) %></li>
<% end %>
```

I also have a admin interface to manage notices(e.g. CRUD).

The problem is that when I open `edit` or `new` page for `notice`.
It will report `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` for `<% @notices.each do |notice| %>`.

Now I can only get away with this by adding a `<% if @notices %>` before the `.each` block.

UPDATE:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :set_notice

  def set_notice
    @notices = Notice.all
  end
end

app/views/notices/_notice_board.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_notices__notice_board_html_erb__624099781_29657256'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___900927418_28913616'
```

Comment: please show controller where you define `@notices`

Comment: It's telling you to initialize `@notices` variable inside controller's method. Can you post the error stack trace to see which controller and method is being called in your case?

Comment: @cqcn1991 : can you post a stack trace which also includes which controller you're calling and the controller's class definition as well? Make sure you have that controller inherited from `ApplicationController` in order to this arrangement work for you.

Comment: @User089247 it's the `Notices#Edit` or`Notices#new `. It's generated by `scaffold`. Nothing special.

Comment: @cqcn1991 : Do you have `set_notice ` method inside `NoticesController`? If yes, then comment/remove it and then try again.

Comment: @User089247 I tried, and didn't work at all. `form_for(@notice)` need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :set_notice

  def set_notice
    @notices = Notice.all
  end
end
```

to this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :set_notices

  def set_notices
    @notices = Notice.all
  end
end
```

Things you can learn from this is that always try to avoid such naming conventions of a method. Since, you're setting `@notices`(plural), your method name should also be plural: `set_notices`. In your case `set_notice` method is being overridden by method defined with the same name in `NoticesController`. Changing the method name as mentioned above should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your sidebar is shared only across all actions of your admins_controller define a private method to get @notices in admins_controller, and put before_filter at the beginning of the controller.

in admins_controller ::

```
before_filter :prepare_notices

def show
end

def edit
end

...
private
 def prepare_notices
  @notices = YOUR_QUERY
 end
```

**If your sidebar will be rendered across the whole website** move the code to your application_controller and before any request to you server this method will be executed.

**If your sidebar will be rendered with some actions in your website** you should put the get_notices method in the application_controller and use before_filter in each controller specifying the actions that will render the sidebar only.

Comment: This is exactly how I define my `@notices`. Seems like it can't help.

Comment: I'm sure it works but let me know how exactly you do it may i can help you.